# Can Pycharm select current word when searching?

Tags: pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Most applications select the whole word at the current cursor position when searching, but PyCharm doesn't seem to do this. I know I can double click or do <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd> then <kbd>Shift + Ctrl + Right</kbd> before hitting <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd>, but it's not ideal.

Am I missing something? I can't see an option to turn on that selects the current word by default.

Comment: You could use `Edit | Extend Selection` (Ctrl+W) to quickly select what's under cursor before hitting Ctrl+F... Anyway: if all what you need is to search current file for word under cursor -- try **BrowseWordAtCaret** plugin -- works well for me.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks. Ctrl-W is better than ctrl-left,right and the plugin is handy too - it's pretty much what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the [PyCharm keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html) and the best match is <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> `Extend Selection` (before using <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> to search). It's configured by default but can also be constumized in `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap`.

[image: image of settings keymap]

There is also a plugin at JetBrains Marketplace called [BrowseWordAtCaret](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/201-browsewordatcaret) that: *"Allows to easily browse next/previous word at caret and highlight other appearances of selected word."*